# scrolling list view color change in android

Tags: android, listview, colors, scroll

I have a problem with the `ListView`'s color while scrolling. When I scroll the ListView, by default I am getting orange color in divider. How to change the color of divider  when scrolling the ListView? Can anyone help me?...

my code is:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"    >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your xml listview layout

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: when we scroll the list view that particular item divider color should change.

Comment: yes. I given divider color as transparent even though it displaying yellow color in divider only when scrolling the list view.

Comment: if you are using emulator for testing, that orange color will be shown when scrolling with mouse...

Comment: thats not a bug. its the property when using emulator.. You need not worry about that. Try it on a real device. That color will not be shown..

Answer (score 1):

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:background="#4a006f"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
```

You Must Declare this tag in `ListView`: `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"`

Answer (score 0):

You should set the CacheColorHint

Use this method:

setCacheColorHint(Color.ONE_OF_YOUR_COLORS). 
You don't need to change the list items' background color.
You can do also in the xml layout.